# Uncaught TypeError in CHROME

Tags: google-chrome, popup

I asked same question before. But it still has error on CHROME, but it works great on IE.
Parent html calls mycoupon3.jsp as popup window and if one of row inside popup was selected, it send INNERHTML to parent html.

The problem is, data from popup not transacted to parent html. On chrome dubugging tools said Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tot' of undefined on "opener.document.joinform.all["tot"].innerHTML". Also popup doesn't self.close.

I think all["tot"] has not compatible with chrome.
So changed it to opener.document.joinform.getelementbyid["tot"].innerHTML, but has no luck.

Here is code.

```
<parent html>

 <td id="tot" class="text_orange"><%=NumberFormat.getInstance().format(cmbean.getTotal())%> USD</td>

 <a href="javascript: mycoupon()"><img src="/images/main/mycoupon_btn.gif" border="0"></a>


<script>

var new_window_handle;  

function mycoupon() {     
new_window_handle = window.open("my_coupon3.jsp?amt=<%=pay_price2%>", 'coupon_win', 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes, resizable=no,width=780,height=540'); 
} 

</script>   

<my_coupon3.jsp> * POPUP window

<script>
function sel_coupon(c_id, amt) {
var tot = opener.document.joinform.Org_totalprice.value ;
tot = String( Number(tot) - Number(amt) ) ;
opener.document.joinform.totalprice.value = tot;
opener.document.joinform.coupon_id.value = c_id ;
opener.document.joinform.all["tot"].innerHTML = maskNum    (opener.document.joinform.Org_totalprice.value) + "USD - " + maskNum(amt) +" USD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color='red'>TOTAL : " + maskNum(tot) + " USD</font></b> ";
opener.cal_payment_money() ;
self.close();
}
</script>

<a href="javascript: sel_coupon('BGG30055901', '3000')"> Apply This coupon</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` isn't an object, it's a function. Call it:

```
document.getElementById('tot')
```

Note that you have to apply it to `document`; individual elements do not have `getElementById`. That's the issue in using `.all` as well; although Chrome supports `all` for the sake of compatibility with pages designed for Internet Explorer, it only supports it as a property of `document`.

Comment: Thanks. but chrome debugger said / Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLFormElement] has no method 'getElementById'

Comment: @paulycho: When I say `document.getElementById`, I mean `opener.document.getElementById`, and not `opener.document.joinform.getElementById`. (Please make sure to read the rest of the answer, not just the first sentence.)

Comment: Thanks. I solved this problem. I wrote wrong capital letter to "getElementById". Chrome is case sensitive..

Comment: All the browsers are case-sensitive, FYI :)